# Unable to set preferences when inheriting from a dialogue preference

Tags: android, preference

I have created a custom preference extending dialogue preference, just like a edittextpreference for example.

The key difference is I am using `android.support.v7.preference.DialogPreference;`

vs the standard `DialogPreference.`

e.g.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class TogglePreferenceTest extends DialogPreference {

    public TogglePreferenceTest(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TogglePreferenceTest(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TogglePreferenceTest(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public View getView(View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            ((LinearLayout) convertView)
                    .setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            TextView txtInfo = new TextView(getContext());

            txtInfo.setText("Test");
            ((LinearLayout) convertView).addView(txtInfo,
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

            ToggleButton btn = new ToggleButton(getContext());
            ((LinearLayout) convertView).addView(btn);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

If I call

```
 PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(mContext, preferences, true);
```

then I get the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: customcontrols.TogglePreferenceTest cannot be cast to android.preference.Preference
```

If I change the DialogPreference to the standard version, then I don't get a crash on startup, but when I go into my settings screen which is defined as

```
import android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceManager;
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
```

then it crashes with `TogglePreferenceTest cannot be cast to android.support.v7.preference.Preference`

What do I do?! Why cant I use
`PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(mContext, preferences, true);`  with the support classes? Especially considering android.support.v7.preference.DialogPreference extends preference, although technically its extending android.support.v7.preference.Preference